# How to hide previous and next link/buttons on last/first single post template

Tags: php, css, wordpress, blogs

im trying to create buttons on single post template with previous/next functionality. I kind of was able to do it but i have couple of issues.

When I'm on first post then I get this error on "next post" button: Warning: Attempt to read property "ID". Same for last post and "previous post" button.

Code that Im using:

```
<div id="post-nav" class="navigation">
    
<?php $prevPost = get_previous_post(true); $prev = get_adjacent_post(true,'',true); if($prevPost) ?>
        
    
    
<div class="col_nav">               

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prev->ID);?>"><div class="nav_bar_1"><div class="nav_text_1">Vorheriger Beitrag:
<p><?php echo get_the_title($prev->ID );?></p></div></div></a>
            
<div class="nav_pic">   
  <?php $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID ); previous_post_link("$prevthumbnail", TRUE); ?>
</div>

</div>
    

    
<?php $nextPost = get_next_post(true); $next = get_adjacent_post(true,'',false); if($nextPost) ?>   
    

<div class="col_nav">       

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($next->ID);?>"><div class="nav_bar_2"><div class="nav_text_2">Nächster Beitrag:
<p><?php echo get_the_title($next->ID );?></p></div></div></a>

<div class="nav_pic">
  <?php $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID ); next_post_link("$nextthumbnail", TRUE); ?>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#post-nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#post-nav img{
    object-fit: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.col_nav {
    Float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

.nav_bar_1, .nav_bar_2{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index:10;
    display: flex;  
    align-items: center;
    padding:0 50px 0 50px;
}

.nav_bar_1{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.0));
}

.nav_bar_2{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left,rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.0));
    justify-content: right;
}

.nav_text_2{
    text-align: right;
}

.col_nav p{
    font-size:22px;
    margin:0;
}

.nav_pic {
    opacity:0.7;
    transition:0.5s ease all;
    height:180px;
}

.col_nav:hover .nav_pic{
    opacity:1;
}

#text_block-86-99 a{
    color:white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .col_nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col_nav p{
    font-size:19px !important;
  }
  .nav_pic {
    height:150px !important;
  }
  .nav_text_2{
    text-align: right;
  }
  .nav_bar_1, .nav_bar_2{
    padding:0 40px 0 40px !important;
  }
}   

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav_bar_1, .nav_bar_2{
    padding:0 20px 0 20px !important;
  }
  .col_nav p{
    font-size:16px !important;
  }
    h2{
        font-size:27px !important;
    }
    h3{
        font-size:23px !important;
    }
}
```

How can I hide button entirely if there is no next or previous post? Or at least hide this message?

Comment: Both get_previous_post and get_next_post will return an empty string, when no corresponding post exists - so simply test for that, before you output these buttons?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Question what should i modify in my code so that the button will be hidden if there is no next or previous post?

Comment: It looks like you already tried to check, `if($prevPost) ?>`- but where is the corresponding `endif` statement?

Comment: There is none i suppose? I tried to mix different codes from different tutorials online, my knowledge is quite limited in terms of PHP, im ok with CSS only.

Comment: And this is not giving you a parse error? Not sure what exactly `if($prevPost) ?>` actually does, when there is no `:` and no `{` either. Try and follow this format: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php